# How to control font in lstlisting (\everypar, frame=<not_none>)

Tags: listings, fontsize, everypar

This piece of code produces different font sizes in the listings depending on whether `frame = lines` is there.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter
\def\@afterheading{\everypar{\fontsize{9.5pt}{12pt}\selectfont}}
\makeatother

\lstset{
    frame = lines,% SOMETHING IS GOING ON HERE
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\fontsize{20pt}{10pt}\selectfont
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
12312313
\end{lstlisting}

\section{A heading}

\begin{lstlisting}
12312313
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And if I remove `frame = lines,` then

[image]

Comment: why do you redefine \@afterheading like this?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I don't. I have a class for a book and I'm localizing it now. It has a complex structure to deal with different font sizes in different paragraphs.

Comment: well it looks very dubious to reset the font size like this.